# Can't send file using res.sendFile to OpenShift

Tags: javascript, node.js, openshift

I'm trying to send a file using `express` in `NodeJS` server. On localhost it works, but when I push my application to OpenShift, I have an error: `Internal Server Error`.

Code:

```
var path = require('path');
app.get('/load', function(req, res) {
    //res.send("TRY");
    res.sendFile(path.resolve('bg95.png'));
});
```

If I try to send simple text, it's ok. So, where coulb be the problem and how to solve it?

Comment: Are you sure that `bg95.png` is in the same directory as your script?

Comment: If you add an Express error handler (e.g. `app.use(function(err, req, res, next) { console.log(err.stack); next(err); }`) after your route handler, what does the error say?

Comment: @mscdex There is no error... Everything is ok in console.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is most likely because you are running in a different working directory. `path.resolve` will use the current working directory unless you provide a `from` argument. Try replacing:

```
res.sendFile(path.resolve('bg95.png'));
```

with

```
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'bg95.png'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, I had a sample **index.html** file in my project folder. I tried `res.sendFile('./dashboard.html')` , `res.sendFile('./app-root/repo/dashboard.html')`, etc. and none of them worked.
Make sure your express version is **v4.8.0** or above. Then I found the below mentioned link, and used the

> `res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));`

where **__dirname**, which I believe gives us the OpenShift's working path folder. This helped me in displaying the page.

https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-expressjs-to-deliver-html-files

Check out this link. A simple demonstration on how to use it, if you follow that, you will be able to make it work. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should update express version in dependecies. Like that:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "4.10.2",
    "socket.io": "1.3.7"
  }
```

It seems the problem is with express version, that doesn't support sendFile.